# ePub mimetype - anyone encountered a situation where it's needed?

Tags: mime-types, epub

I'm wondering if anyone has ever encountered a situation where it was necessary that the mimetype file be put into the zip file first (and uncompressed) to make the ePub work. And I'm not talking about the ability to pass an ePub validation.

I've been trying to write a script to create ePubs and it's not working. I tried several variations of the 7zip flags and every time the validation complains about the mimetype file.

I got fed up and just opened one of the files in Digital Editions and it worked fine. Then opened it in Calibre, dropped it into Chrome (ePub Reader), in iBooks, and even made a Kindle file. Everything worked as expected without throwing up an error.

Is there *any* situation where this matters...apart from the OCD part of me wanting an error-free file?

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to be "no"...

But here are a sampling of posts fighting with the Mimetype file error:

- [Make MIMETYPE file the first file in an EPUB ZIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924095/make-mimetype-file-the-first-file-in-an-epub-zip-file?rq=1)
- [Creating an Epub file with a Zip library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5898787/creating-an-epub-file-with-a-zip-library?rq=1)
- [creating *.epub with perl Archive::Zip -- epubchecker error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698579/creating-epub-with-perl-archivezip-epubchecker-error?rq=1)
- [How to create ePub with System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645392/how-to-create-epub-with-system-io-compression-ziparchive?rq=1)
- [The mimetype file has an extra field of length n. The use of the extra field feature of the ZIP format is not permitted for the mimetype file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726113/the-mimetype-file-has-an-extra-field-of-length-n-the-use-of-the-extra-field-fea?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this validation error while building an epub with the `zip` command line tool on my Macbook. What worked for me was using the `-X` command line option.

```
$ zip -rX book.epub mimetype META-INF ...
```

The man file says this about the `-X` option:

```
-X
--no-extra
    Do not save extra file attributes (Extended Attributes on OS/2, uid/gid and file times on Unix).  The zip format uses extra fields to include
    additional information for each entry.  Some extra fields are specific to particular systems while others are applicable to all systems.
    Normally when zip reads entries from an existing archive, it reads the extra fields it knows, strips the rest, and adds the extra fields
    applicable to that system.  With -X, zip strips all old fields and only includes the Unicode and Zip64 extra fields (currently these two extra
    fields cannot be disabled).
```

After adding the `-X` option, the validator no longer flagged the mimetype issue.